ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. While i have SSL certificate installed
I hosted my website on a VPS using Hostinger as provider. I added my backend and frontend using pm2 and I pointed the ip address to my domain that I bought from hostinger cloud hosting plan that has ssl certificate I installed the certificate. ut when I open my website it only opens as http and tells me not secure when i try to write it down as https it gives me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I just need some help so I can host my website with secure connection.
I tried re installing it again. and I tried to get path of certificate but it is not available on hostinger to get path
I access my domain through domain name:3000 so if anyone could help so I can get it secured

Without more information, it's difficult to help you directly. With that said, Hostinger has resources on SSL here that may be helpful.
Also, if you haven't heard of it, maybe look in to Cloudflare. If you just need simple SSL, Cloudflare may be a good option. Here's some more info on that.
